# Cors issue solved by using proxy not working after served in Netlify Create-react-app

Tags: api, deployment, cors, create-react-app, netlify

I have built a real estate site that makes a an api request to "https://completecriminalchecks.com" In development mode I was getting the dreaded blocked by Cors error. Through some research I found that I needed to use a proxy to solve the issue, which it did in development mode on my local host. But now I have deployed the site to netlify, I am getting a 404 error when making the request. when I look at the request from the network devtools its says

Request URL: https://master--jessehaven.netlify.app/api/json/?apikey=6s4xxxxx13xlvtphrnuge19&search=radius&miles=2&center=98144

I dont think this is right. How do i make netlify make the proper request to the api that was having cors issues in development?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried netify [documentation](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#proxy-to-another-service) about it?

> Proxy to another service Just like you can rewrite paths like /* to
>   /index.html, you can also set up rules to let parts of your site proxy
>   to external services. Let's say you need to communicate from a
>   single-page app with an API on https://api.example.com that doesn't
>   support CORS requests. The following rule will let you use /api/ from
>   your JavaScript client:
>
> ```
> /api/*  https://api.example.com/:splat  200
> ```
>
> Now all requests to /api/... will be proxied through to
>   https://api.example.com straight from our CDN servers without an
>   additional connection from the browser. If the API supports standard
>   HTTP caching mechanisms like ETags or Last-Modified headers, the
>   responses will even get cached by our CDN nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use a proxy, you enable CORRS in your server.  Are you using a onde server?

If you use express something like this:

```
npm install --save cors
```

And then use it as middleware:

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();
app.use(cors());
```

Also in your netlify.toml file this will do the trick:

```
# The following redirect is intended for use with most SPAs that handle
# routing internally.
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200

[[headers]]
  # Define which paths this specific [[headers]] block will cover.
  for = "/*"
    [headers.values]
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"
```

Comment: im not using a server. just using create react app. And react router.

Comment: i am having the same issue. it works find on local, but when I upload to netlify... CORS blocks api calls.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue and solved by creating a netlify.toml file in root directory.
Here is a sample code for redirect which worked for me.

Place this inside the netlify.toml file.

[Documentation guide for proxy :](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/)

```
 [[redirects]]
  from = "/api/users/tickets/"
  to = "https://some-external-site.com/api/users/tickets/"
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"}

[[redirects]]
  from = "/api/users/cars/*"
  to = "https://some-external-site.com/api/users/cars/:splat"
  status = 200
  force = true
  headers = {Access-Control-Allow-Origin = "*"}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue , so I removed the "**proxy**" from the "**package.json**" file and created a variable to store the IP addess or URL for backend , then used it with the URL parameter for calling API. The CORS issue is solved in backend by allowing "All origins".

File to store base URL:

constant.js :

```
export const baseUrl = "https://backEndUrl";
```

File to call API:

getDataApi.js:

```
import { baseUrl } from "./constant";

export const getProfileData = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios
    .get(`${baseUrl }/api/profile`)
    .then((res) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: res.data,
      })
    )
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_PROFILE,
        payload: null,
      })
    );
};
```